# How to learn to sample?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, autoencoders

Imagine you have access to a dataset of pairs $(s, \hat{\pi}(s))$ where s is a state in a high dimension continuous space $S$, $\pi(s)$ is a probabilistic distribution on a large **discrete** space $D$ (size around $10^{9}$), and $\hat{\pi}(s)$ is a sample from this distribution.

A detail is important : $\pi$ is not a distribution right, it's $\pi(s)$ who is one.

My question is simple : how can an algorithm learn to, given a state s, sample from $\pi(s)$ ?